# html/javascript: is there any way to make an <img> tag w/o needing an actual image?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to make a single-file HTML test case for something + part of the test case involves IMG tags; is there any way to inline a 1x1 pixel image (either statically in HTML or dynamically via Javascript) without having to refer to an external image?

It's not a huge deal, but if there's an easy way to do this, it would make it easier for me to manage this test case.

Comment: There may be a better way than using an image. What is the end-goal of having the 1x1 image?

Comment: Have you tried `<img src="" width="1" height="1" alt="" />`?  Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here.  If the previous example doesn't work, open up paint or any other graphics program and create a 1x1 pixel image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed the image data using the [Data URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: Ah, cool -- I thought I remembered reading this but wasn't sure where to look or what to search for.

Comment: This is the dataURI for 1 pixel png.

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVR42mNgAAIAAAUAAen63NgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: @caleb, is there an online encoder for such things? How to quickly produce the dataURI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very simple:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAxJREFUCNdj+P//PwAF/gL+3MxZ5wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

Comment: whoops, just realized you want an actual `1x1` image, hold on while i generate the data url...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can inline svg image. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction